# Automated tool to modify python source to support 2.7 and 3.4

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, automation

We want to support Python 2.7 and 3.4+ from one code base in the future.

I searched for automated tools, but lib2to3 seems to only support Python 3 in the result.

I know that the library six could help us, but we have a lot of Python source files.

My dream: A tool that adds this (or even more future imports) to each file:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, unicode_literals, print_function
```

and the tool should update:

- all `u'...'` -->  `'...'`
- `print foo` --> `print(foo)`
- ...

Comment: It seems like lib2to3 does most of what you need, it's just missing the \_\_future__ imports, right? So you could use lib2to3 to make valid python3, then something like awk to add the \_\_future__ imports and make it valid python2 as well. Or have I missed something?

Answer (score -1):

This should work, but up to now untested:

1. use [2to3](https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html)
2. use [3to2](http://www.startcodon.com/wordpress/category/3to2/)